# devMode & PHP7.1

Tags: devmode

I would like to use Craft's devMode but when I set it to true I get the following error: unserialize(): Unexpected end of serialized data. I believe this might be something to do with PHP7 for which this post seemed to have a solution https://www.jackreichert.com/2014/02/handling-a-php-unserialize-offset-error/ but obviously I don't want to start changing core files.

Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: PHP 7.1 is a dev release and is not officially supported yet. P&T are pretty good about addressing these kinds of things so it's likely a future version of Craft will be updated before PHP 7.1 actually ships.